# Wamp MySql not working properly

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

Ive been on google all morning and here on SO. The problem im having is that, im trying to change the password from the default "" value on wamp to something else.

i am working on an app that i started on MAMP on my mac and since i go back and forth between MAc and WINDOWS, i dont want to go back n forth with two versions of the app (one for mamp  and the other for wamp as far as the log in details) so i just want to change the pass on the WAMP.

Ive changed the password on the mysql app "privileges" section and thats when i began having problems to the tune of "denied access etc"

I also(after seeing here on SO somewhere) changed the password in the config.inc file to reflect my phpmyadmin app user account password change, all the while refreshing/restarting the servers and i still am locked out.

im 100% positive that the details im entering are correct.

Fast forward to now, i frustrated, decided to re-install since i was locked out and now when i start the wamp server and try to access phpmyadmin, i am STILL locked out(even after reinstall) and doesnt allow me to connect with "localhost", i have to connect with 127.0.0.1

Any idea on why all this is happening? because i still cant connect to anything when i try to change the password.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you considered using XAMPP for windows? I've never had a problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but always work for me,
before start WAMP allwasy turn Off Skype 
and when wamp is ready turn On Skype.